# linear algebra matrices and matrix operations

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, multilinear-algebra

Show that if a square matrix $A$ satisfies 
                     $A^3 + 4A^2 -2A +7I = O$,
                            then so does $A^T$.

Answer (score 2):

$$A^3+4A^2-2A+7I=0\implies 0=0^T=\left(A^3+4A^2-2A+7I\right)^T=$$

$$=(A^3)^T+(4A^2)^T-(2A)^T+(7I)^T$$

and now use that $\;(A^n)^T=(A^T)^n\;$